# Is there a maximally skewed bounded distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Among all bounded random variable $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|X -\mu_X| \leq B$ for some $B>0$, one with the maximum variance has mass $1/2$ at $B$ and $-B$ each. Is there also a construction for the bounded RV with maximal skewness $(E[(X - \mu_X)^3])$?

I was thinking to maybe approach this as a calculus of variations problem for the pdf $f(x)$ but I'm not sure if I could do that rigorously or if it would be fruitful here. Some intuition would be great.

Comment: Do you want the cube or the absolute value of the cube?

Comment: as you have seen, in case of the second moment one should have started not with a pdf, but just a two-point distribution. Can you find a solution for the third moment optimization for such distributions?

Comment: @Ian I believe I want the cube for the 3rd moment.

Comment: @Ilya If I maximize $E[(X-\mu)^3]$ over $p$ where $X = 1$ w.p. $p$ and $X=0$ w.p. $1-p$ then the max occurs at $p = (1-\sqrt{1/3})/2$. However, how can I be sure that it is general enough to consider two-point distributions?

Comment: Why the second value is $0$? You may need to optimize over it as well. As long as it’s above $-1$. Then you can use scaling argument to generalize it to all other two point distributiona

Comment: If you're considering two-point distributions, can't you WLOG choose one of them to be 0 by shifting the entire distribution, if we're only worried about centered moments? And what if I am interested in general distributions beyond 2 points?